# How to sign-in .NET 5 MVC webapp with KeyCloak using OpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, .net, keycloak, openid-connect, .net-5

I have configured my OpenIdConnect within KeyCloak and now I am trying to connect to it using .NET 5 MVC application.

**How to sign-in correctly?**

This is what I have so far

1. When I try to access protected resource I get redirected to KeyCloak for a correct "relm" to sign in.

[image]

The user can sign in and the application flows through the OpenIDConnect to the method OnTokenValidated.

2. In this event, I can see that the user has successfully logged in and while debugging see the authentication details

   string firstName = idToken.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName)?.Value;

where firstName gets populated to the correct user.

3. Redirect issue

The redirection to my application keeps going into OnTokenValidated as a loop but the application does not register that the user is signed in

My code looks like thus:

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        const string clientId = "demoClient";
        const string clientSecret = "4342abf9-CC85-4cf2-ba83-316c56a523b9";  // representative
        const string authority = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/demo";   // name of authority

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "oidc";
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = "Cookies";
                })
                 .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.CallbackPath = "/home/index";
                options.Authority = authority;
                options.ClientId = clientId;
                options.ClientSecret = clientSecret;
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // dev only
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                //options.Scope.Add("openid");  // TODO: not sure how to configure

                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.Scope.Add("email");

                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = context =>
                    {
                        // short lived code used to authorise the application on back channel
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
                    {
                        //save url to state
                       //  n.ProtocolMessage.State = n.HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToString();
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTicketReceived = context =>
                    {
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?errormessage = " + context.Exception.Message);
                        // context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRemoteFailure = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                };

            });
```

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: I've got the same problem, it ends up in a infinite loop of redirects

Comment: I have found that the implementation of keycloak I have been using did not implement correctly the OpenIDConnection standard and therefore a workaround is required. I have solved it by using older version of keycloak

Comment: interesting.... I actually got it going with the latest keycloak, and seems to work ok.  Though what I can't seem to get working is getting roles coming through from the keycloak server, but I think that's mainly me not quite understanding how to do it.

Comment: @KeithNicholas what version of KeyCloak are you using? Did you setup the roles to be passed through to you in keycloak itself?

Comment: yes, I have 12.0.4 installed, and I've set it up so I can get roles through from keycloak into my .NET 5 app.    So in keycloak I can add users to groups, and groups can have roles and they come through into .net and I can do  User.IsInRole("blahblah")

Comment: If you are interested in what I have done, email me ( see my profile ), I'm actually going through a larger exercise of trying to work out all the toys I need using keycloak and I'm documenting in a github repo ( but currently I have it private as it is very rough and I don't really understand all the settings yet, so it's likely going to change quite a bit as I learn more ).

Comment: I have implemented .NET 5 MVC Web Application which uses above mentioned code for authentication through Keycloak.

I am using Keycloak 16.0.1 and I am facing same redirect issue. Kindly provide suggestions to resolve the same.

Answer (score 0):

To configure an ASP.NET MVC web application client to authenticate with Keycloak use the following configuration:

- Add your client in the realm and set the access type as "confidential"
- Make sure that the authorization is enabled
- If it is a strongly trusted client, you could also enable the Direct Access Grants, but this is optional.

[image]

In the field "Valid Redirect URI" set "https://your.app.uri/signin-oidc" and   "https://your.app.uri/signout-callback-oidc"

In the field "Web Origins" set "*"
In the field "Backchannel Logout URL" you may set "https://your.app.uri/signin-oidc"

[image]

Then configure your client-Id, Authority and Client Secret as you did in the code that you provided in the question.